# Declarar as variáveis no topo ou perto de onde são usadas?

Tags: php, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, declaração-de-variável

É melhor declarar todas as variáveis logo no início do arquivo, mesmo que só venham a ser utilizadas, sei lá, mil linhas depois? Ou é melhor ir declarando conforme o programa evolui?

O meu caso é que vou unir vários *scripts* em apenas um (estou criando cada função separadamente porque estava ficando muito grande e confuso), e quero em dúvida se devo apenas copiar e colar esses arquivos, com as variáveis onde estão (o que está funcionando), ou se é pego todas as variáveis e jogo no início deste arquivo grande, e depois vou colocando apenas as funções.

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma dessas opções? Isso faz diferença no desempenho? Existe um caminho considerado mais correto?

Tipo, é melhor isso:

```
// variáveis e função 1

$reds = $_POST ["Tredsalim"];
$redvalan = $_POST ["Treds4"];
$redvalan2 = $_POST ["Treds9"];

if ($reds == "sim") {
    $remmes += $redvalan + $redvalan2;
}

// variáveis e função 2

$difsal = $_POST ["Tdifsalim"];
$saldev = $_POST ["Tdate5"];
$saldev2 = $_POST ["Tdate9"];
$saldev3 = $_POST ["Tdate13"];

if ($saldev > 1) {
    $remmes = $saldev;
}
if ($saldev2 > 1) {
    $remmes = $saldev2;
}
if ($saldev3 > 1) {
    $remmes = $saldev3;
```

Ou isso:

```
// variáveis caso 1 

$reds = $_POST ["Tredsalim"];
$redvalan = $_POST ["Treds4"];
$redvalan2 = $_POST ["Treds9"];

// variáveis caso 2

$difsal = $_POST ["Tdifsalim"];
$saldev = $_POST ["Tdate5"];
$saldev2 = $_POST ["Tdate9"];
$saldev3 = $_POST ["Tdate13"];

// função 1

if ($reds == "sim") {
    $remmes += $redvalan + $redvalan2;
}

// função 2

if ($saldev > 1) {
    $remmes = $saldev;
}
if ($saldev2 > 1) {
    $remmes = $saldev2;
}
if ($saldev3 > 1) {
    $remmes = $saldev3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente o melhor é garantir que todas as variáveis devem ser declaradas no começo. Isto vai contra o que se costuma recomendar. Mas juntar vários códigos também não é recomendado. Então já que vai fazer algo não recomendado que pelo menos tente minimizar o dano e ele será minimizado se tiver que analisar todo o código para descobrir todas as variáveis para declarar no início. Quem sabe descobre que alguns *bugs* seriam causados por sobreposição de variáveis ou outro conflitos.

Neste exemplo específico fica ainda mais óbvio que deveria fazer isto porque no fundo as variáveis são bem relacionadas, no fundo um grupo é continuação do outro.

Isto deve ser feito só por uma questão de organização, não influencia a performance.

Claro que em outra situação a mudança pode mudar a lógica do código.

Se estiver criando várias funções no mesmo arquivo, aí fica mais simples porque as variáveis viram locais, e tem que ser tudo perto mesmo, não dá para agrupar as variáveis sem criar novos possíveis problemas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, era isso mesmo que estava precisando saber. Os scripts são bem relacionados mesmo, e só coloquei em arquivos diferentes enquanto estou criando para não me confundir. Mas vou fazer isso mesmo, declarar primeiro as variáveis, e vou colocar mais comentários também, porque senão vai ficando impossível trabalhar direito. Valeu!